# 10 year ban after applying for a UK student visa

Tags: uk, visa-bans

I was banned for 10 years through a UK student visa application in 2007 due to a bank statement mismatch issue.

The ban expired in 2017.

I am planning to visit the UK on a standard visitor visa.

Is there any chance that I'll get the visa?

Comment: "Bank statement mismatch issue." You didn't provide specifics, but it sounds like you were banned for deception, which makes a future attempt difficult.

Comment: This situation begs the attention of an immigration attorney, as subtle mistakes on your end could easily result in another 10 year ban.

Answer (score 13):

Technically, yes, why not. Try to prove it to them, with a strong application, that you now fulfill all the conditions for being granted a tourist visa you may well be granted one.

But that's easier said than done after a long ban, that ban will always come up in your future visa applications for the UK, and it might be much more advisable to take help from an immigration specialist in filing your application.

Answer (score 1):

Technically once you have served the ban period that means you are eligible for applying any Visa category for you the United Kingdom. However, the previous ban on your profile with UKVI always comes up with your new application and this will have an impact on your credibility and Entry Clearance Officer may get biased while making the decision.

BUT, this doesn't mean that you have no chance of getting a UK visa, A strong application with proper evidence can increase your chances and a qualified solicitor will always be able to guide you in a more better way.